# Cpp error while compiling a plugin for cocos2d-x

Tags: android, c++, makefile, cocos2d-x

I'm trying to write an Android plugin for cocos2dx. But I seem to have hit a (basic?) c++ obstacle.
I'm encountering the following error-see below: (shortVersion - "'ProtocolAds' does not name a type.").

```
make.exe: Entering directory `C:/Android/Cocos2d/cocos2d-x-cocos2d-x-3.6/CocosPr
ojectWoobiDemo/proj.android'
[armeabi] Compile++ thumb: cocos2dcpp_shared <= HelloWorldScene.cpp
[armeabi] StaticLibrary  : libcocos2d.a
[armeabi] StaticLibrary  : libcocostudio.a
[armeabi] StaticLibrary  : libcocosbuilder.a
[armeabi] StaticLibrary  : libcocos3d.a
[armeabi] StaticLibrary  : libspine.a
[armeabi] StaticLibrary  : libnetwork.a
[armeabi] StaticLibrary  : libui.a
[armeabi] StaticLibrary  : libaudioengine.a
[armeabi] StaticLibrary  : libcocosdenshion.a
[armeabi] StaticLibrary  : flatbuffers.a
[armeabi] StaticLibrary  : libextension.a
[armeabi] StaticLibrary  : libcocos2dxinternal.a
[armeabi] StaticLibrary  : libbox2d.a
[armeabi] StaticLibrary  : libcocos2dandroid.a
[armeabi] StaticLibrary  : libcpufeatures.a
[armeabi] Gdbserver      : [arm-linux-androideabi-4.9] libs/armeabi/gdbserver
[armeabi] Gdbsetup       : libs/armeabi/gdb.setup
jni/../../Classes/HelloWorldScene.cpp: In member function 'void HelloWorld::test
Func()':
jni/../../Classes/HelloWorldScene.cpp:97:24: error: 'ProtocolAds' does not name
a type
  _woobi = dynamic_cast<ProtocolAds*>(PluginManager::getInstance()->loadPlugin("
Woobi"));
```

To the best of my understanding, does not name a type is an error that comes when the linker does not know the object's class (for any possible reason).

My Thoughts:

- The error is "error: 'ProtocolAds' does not name a type"
- The error happens in a .cpp file that has this line in: #include "ProtocolAds.h"
- The header file for the above .cpp file has the same line: #include "ProtocolAds.h". And a call for this line: cocos2d::plugin::ProtocolAds* _woobi; And it looks like this file has no problem with ProtocolAds. (since if i'm not calling ProtocolAds from the .cpp file, the .h compiles and links without error)

How is that possible? I've been reading and trying for a huge amount of time and no win. Can anyone please help?

Comment: are you going to post any code? how ProtocolAds was defined?

Comment: ProtocolAds was defined inside a closed library so i can't post its code.

Comment: My .h file : #ifndef __HELL
#define __HELL

#include "cocos2d.h"
#include "ProtocolAds.h"

class HelloWorld : public cocos2d::Layer
{
public:
    void testFunc();

private:
    cocos2d::plugin::ProtocolAds* _woobi;
};

#endif // __HELLOWORLD_SCENE_H__
My .cpp file: #include "HelloWorldScene.h"

USING_NS_CC;
Scene* HelloWorld::createScene()
{
    auto scene = Scene::create();
    this->testFunc(); //HelloWorld::testFunc()?
    return scene;
}

void HelloWorld::testFunc()
{
 //the horror
 _woobi = dynamic_cast<ProtocolAds*>(PluginManager::getInstance()->loadPlugin("Woobi"));

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like adding the following two lines to the header works:

--#include "PluginManager.h" 
using namespace cocos2d::plugin;

The use of this namespacing is untrivial to an non cpp developer. 
Considering these files are in a precompiled library, how are you supposed to figure out that ProtocolAds.h is in the namespace of cocos2d::plugin?

I've doubt it would, but hope this will help at least one person outside myself.

Answer (score 0):

it seems you should use it with namespace specifiers: `dynamic_cast<cocos2d::plugin::ProtocolAds*>`

Comment: It looks like adding the following two lines to the header works: #include "PluginManager.h"
using namespace cocos2d::plugin; But I don't understand why.